# Get data from cells in a row and populate a new row in google sheets

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I'm a total noob with scripts.

The idea is to get the data from the row of one sheet and then populate the row of the second sheet once a day.

I have 2 sheets with a spreadsheet.
 1. A parent list of text in column 1 and numbers in column 2.
 2. A target sheet to be populated.

From what I understand I have to do this

1. identify the parent sheet
2. identify the target sheet
3. set a variable (R) for the row of the parent sheet to get data from
4. find the data in column 1 of the parent sheet on row R
5. find the date in column 2 of the parent sheet on row R
6. Go to first empty row in the target sheet
7. Fill column 1 of the target sheet with data from column 1 of the parent sheet
8. repeat for column 2
9. update R to R+1 so when the function is triggered the next day then it gets the data from the next row.

I think that makes sense, but haven't got a clue of how to code that.

Would looooove the help of someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

I manged to do steps 1 - 5 but stuck on one aspect.

Each day I want the script to go to the next row in the parent sheet.

I tried to set up a var currentRow for this, but when I put it within or out of the function it always goes back to 1.

```js
var currentRow = 1;

function myFunction() {
  // create a variable to know what row to get the data from in the parent list
  
  Logger.log(currentRow);
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var parent = ss.getSheetByName("parent");
  var range = parent.getDataRange(),
      values = range.getValues();
  
  var row = values[currentRow],
      text = row[0],
      video = row[1];

   Logger.log(text);
   Logger.log(video);
  
  currentRow = currentRow + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice I managed to work out how to do it all.

I changed the currentRow to instead figure out what is the last row number in the target sheet.

Then the script adds 1 to that and get the data from the next row of the parent sheet.

This stuff is fun!

```js
function myFunction() {
  // create a variable to know what row to get the data from in the parent list
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var parent = ss.getSheetByName("parent");
  var range = parent.getDataRange(),
      values = range.getValues(),
      lastRow = parent.getLastRow();
  
  //get the position of the last row in the populate sheet
  var populate = ss.getSheetByName("populate"),
      range = parent.getDataRange(),
      lastPopulateRow = populate.getLastRow();
  
  var row = values[lastPopulateRow + 1],
      text = row[0],
      video = row[1];

   Logger.log(text);
   Logger.log(video);
   Logger.log(lastRow);
   Logger.log(lastPopulateRow);
  
  
  //append to the populate sheet
  populate.appendRow([text, video]);

}
```